# require and readFile async

Tags: node.js

I'm using express and I want to put some configurations in a file(like database configuration, api credentials and other basic stuffs).

Now I'm putting this configuration in a JSON and I read this file using readAsync.

Reading some code I noted a lot of people use don`t use a JSON.. Instead, they use a common JS file and exports in a module.

Is there any difference between these approaches, like performace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latter way probably simplifies version control, testing and builds, and makes it easier to have separate configurations for production and development. It also lets you do a little "preprocessing" like defining "constants" for common setups.

In a well-designed application, the performance of configuration-reading is going to be completely irrelevant.

If you go with the latter, you need to practice some discipline: a configuration module should consist almost entirely of literals, with only enough executable code to handle things like distinguishing between development and production. Beware of letting application logic creep into it.

Answer (score 1):

In node.js require works synchronously, but it's not very important if you load configurations once on the application starts. Asynchronously way realy need only if you loading configurations many times (for each request for example).

Answer (score 0):

In node.js you can simply require your json files:

config.json:

```
{
  "db": "127.0.0.1/database"
}
```

app.js:

```
var config = require('./config');

console.log(config);
```

If you need something more full featured I would use [flatiron/nconf](https://github.com/flatiron/nconf).